# How do I set schema.org metatag for products?

Tags: 8, commerce, meta-tags

I'm using https://www.drupal.org/project/schema_metatag for my Drupal 8 + Drupal commerce 2 online store and the question is - how to configure fields and what tokens should be used to display products as schema.org Product type?
[image: product metatag]
Thanks you!

Comment: This depends a bit on your products field structure. the product title would be for example [commerce_product:title]